# Factor Analysis: Simulating observations from predetermined factor loadings with beta-distributed variables

Tags: simulation, factor-analysis, beta-distribution

I have a question about simulating data in the context of (exploratory) factor analysis.

I need to simulate n observations of p measurable variables derived from k latent variables given factor loadings for each measurable variable. That is, given a p x k matrix of factor loadings, I'd like to generate a set of n plausible observations. The output should be an n x p matrix of simulated observations. When factor analysis is performed on the simulated data, I should get values similar to the original factor loadings.

One hitch, the values in each column of the n x p simulated observations matrix should (roughly) follow a beta distribution.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, but with dubious help from Google and ChatGPT, I put together some code. These are the steps that ChatGPT told me follow:

1. define the p x k matrix of factor loadings (I'll call it *loadings*).
2. generate an n x k matrix of random, normally distributed factor scores, which I'll call *factors*.
3. generate an n x p matrix of random, beta distributed observations, which I'll call *observations*.
4. take the dot product of *factors* and *loadings* (transposed) and add *observations*. The result is the (more or less) final simulated observations.

I'm not sure I really understand what ChatGPT is trying to do here, but it doesn't work. When I perform a new factor analysis on the simulated observations, the factor loadings are nothing like those in *loadings* and the variables don't load the way they should either (even given the possibility of poles flipping).

So, I have two questions:

1. Has ChatGPT put me on the right track and I'm just missing something silly?
2. If no, does anyone have a better way to do this?

Python code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from factor_analyzer import Rotator, FactorAnalyzer

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(123)

# Define the number of observations and variables
n = 1000
p = 6

# Define the factor loadings matrix
loadings = np.array([[0.6, 0.4, 0.0],
                     [0.4, 0.5, 0.1],
                     [0.3, 0.2, 0.7],
                     [0.0, 0.8, 0.4],
                     [0.7, 0.0, 0.5],
                     [0.0, 0.6, 0.4]])

# Define the number of factors
k = loadings.shape[1]

# Generate the latent factor scores
factors = np.random.normal(0,.1,size=(n, k))

# Generate the standardized observed variables with beta distribution
observed = np.random.beta(2, 5, size=(n, p))

# Compute the observed variables as a linear combination of the latent factors
observed = np.dot(factors, loadings.T) + observed

# Test the simulated data by fitting a new FA model
# If the simulation worked, the loadings from the new model should be similar to the loadings
# specified above.
 
# Fit factor analysis model to the simulated data
# Method='principal' to use OLS instead of MLE (vars are not normally distributed)
fa = FactorAnalyzer(rotation='varimax', method='principal')
fa.fit(observed)

# Print the standardized factor loadings
print(fa.loadings_)
```

The output:

```
 [[-0.01295672  0.87588893 -0.02321431]
  [ 0.28134231  0.49612987  0.19610379]
  [ 0.21686871 -0.11089673  0.76680512]
  [ 0.72838621  0.1062238   0.12636419]
  [-0.06024928  0.28948084  0.73527448]
  [ 0.77707454  0.05032242  0.01255114]]
```

As you can see, the matrix is different enough from *loadings* to indicate something went seriously wrong.

Go easy on me folks. I'm a linguist.

Comment: This is not the exact answer you're looking for, but there are a lot of functions to simulate factor analysis in R, e.g.: https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/sim.html